# Reindexing plan

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, maintenance

I have a reindexing plan failing with error message:

> Refresh failed for PhysicalPartition '1'

(Details: SQL Server Enterprise edition running in cluster.)

Searching through BOL and other online resources gave no pointers at all. What could this be related to?

Comment: What do you mean by reindexing plan? A SQL Server maintenance plan? `SELECT * FROM sys.messages where text like '%Refresh failed%'` doesn't return any results for me so not sure that error actually comes directly from SQL Server. Maybe you could try tracing the queries and error messages for the plan to see what exactly is failing.

Comment: @MartinSmith, thank you. Yes it is a server maintenance plan. Any handy pointers on how to setup a trace on a maintenance plan.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue occurs on the cluster node where the physical disk resource did not come online.

@Unreason: Before this problem started did u install any security update for Symantec Endpoint Protection.

1. Check the events are logged in the Windows Server
2. Check the Cluster log.

If you figure out it is because of the Symantec update. The [Solution](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH97096&locale=en_US) is

**Solution**

Symantec has released a product to resolve this issue. The fix has been included in Symantec Endpoint Protection 11 RU6.

**Note:** SEP 11 RU5 was the first client with official support for Windows 2008 R2. Migrate up to SEP 11 RU6 to resolve this issue, or downgrade to SEP11 MR4 MP2 if your policies require you to test with the newly released support products before introducing them in your production environment. SEP11 MR4 MP2 can be installed to Sever 2008 R2, but you first must install Liveupdate (lusetup.exe), and then install the MR4 MP2 client.

**References**
Location to download Microsoft Handle tool - http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/Handle.zip

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but not we do not use Symantec. Will try to use handle to dig deeper. It is already helpful to better understand where to look for.